# Casting to subtype in Mockito argLambda matcher

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, mockito

I'm trying to use Mockito's [argLambda matcher](https://github.com/szpak/mockito-java8#lambda-matcher) to match on a field of an argument. The problem I'm running into is that the method that I'm trying to mock takes a superclass which doesn't have the field/getter I'm trying to match on. Because of this I can't access the getter of the subclass in order to match. Is there a way to cast the lambda argument to the subclass, or some other alternative solution to this.

The superclass:

```
public abstract class SuperC {
    public abstract void doCoolStuff();
}
```

The subclass:

```
public class SubC extends SuperC{
    private final String someField;
    public String getSomeField() { return someField; }

    public SubC(String f){ this.someField = f; }

    @Override public void doCoolStuff() {}
}
```

The class I'm trying to test:

```
public class Target {
    private final Dependency dependency;

    public Target(Dependency d){ this.dependency = d; }

    public String testMe(String s){
        SubC myC = new SubC(s);

        // Want to mock this method that takes a SuperC
        return this.dependency.doThings(myC);
    }
}
```

The dependency class:

```
public class Dependency {
    // Want to mock this method that takes a SuperC
    public String doThings(SuperC c){ return "NOT MOCKED"; }
}
```

The test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static info.solidsoft.mockito.java8.LambdaMatcher.argLambda;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TargetTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Dependency mockDependency = Mockito.mock(Dependency.class);

        // s is SuperC
        when(mockDependency.doThings(argLambda(s -> s.getSomeField()
                  .equals("EXPECTED")))).thenReturn("MOCK");

        Target target = new Target(mockDependency);
        assertEquals("MOCK", target.testMe("EXPECTED"));
    }
}
```

In this line I cannot call s.getSomeField since s resolves to a SuperC.

```
        // s is SuperC
        when(mockDependency.doThings(argLambda(s -> s.getSomeField()
                  .equals("EXPECTED")))).thenReturn("MOCK");
```

The error:

```
Error:(16, 62) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getSomeField()
  location: variable s of type TestingJava.SuperC
```

Comment: You mean this `s -> ((SubC) s).getSomeField().equals("EXPECTED")`? But this looks like this could use some generic type.

Comment: Thanks that works. Would you mind going into detail on your suggestion of using generic type?